# RSS Reader has blank screen of webview when link is pressed

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, webview, rss

I am creating an RSS Reader for www.platform-online.net , and I am completely stuck as to why the web page will not show when an RSS link is pressed.

I'm sure it's involving webview somehow, so I give you the two classes that involves it:

```
> package com.daryl.rssreader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.*;


import com.daryl.platform.R;


public class PostViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setContentView(R.layout.postview);
        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        String postContent = bundle.getString("content");

        webView = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadData(postContent, "text/html; charset=utf-8","utf-8");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

The XML file called 'postview.xml'

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"  >

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/> 

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

Forgive me if i'm not giving enough information to see the problem, but I can give more detail if needed.

I would show you links to how the app shows now, but i don't have enough 'reputation'.

Completely at a loss, the code is mostly from here:
http://jmsliu.com/1390/rss-reader-app-android-tutorial-1-listview-and-arrayadapter.html

But the person in question doesn't give much help towards a solution.

If anyone is able to help me out after a good 12 hours of analysing everything I've done thus far, it would be greatly appreciated as I'm completely at a brick wall.

Thank you.

Comment: So I tried using the xml link used in the tutorial on the link, and it shows the webpage fine, so it must be the rss feed given from Platform. But when I replace it with Platform (http://platform-online.net/feed?paged=) the problem returns. But this is now where i'm stuck. So perhaps its not web view, but the RSS feed itself?

Comment: The site is also running off WordPress.org if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change your xml file to this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"  >
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

In your xml file there is no space for webview because your `LinearLayout` set as `math_parent`

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work. Would the RSS Feed given in the MainActivity.java file be responsible due to its format or not? private String urlString = "http://feeds.feedburner.com/PlatformOnline?format=xml";